# libgdx building 3D terrain

Tags: java, libgdx, terrain

I've been spending a lot of my time working with libgdx scene 2d & have become very familiar with it. I've decided I want to move over to 3D & take a couple of weeks to learn & better understand the 3D side.

I've gotten a clear understanding of loading 3D objects, camera, & more. Where I'm stuck is deciding which method for loading a terrain is best &/or a decently clear tutorial/snippet on loading a 3D terrain tiled terrain without the use of a height-map & I can learn on my own from there.

A specific terrain in mind is a grid terrain. Similar to the first image w/ multi-texturing (smooth textures - paint effect) similar to the second image.

[image]

[image]

Places/repositories I have taken into account & have thoroughly taken a look into.

Fabula-Engine (Decent but hastle to understand & get working), gdx-proto (decent but the terrain is created using a meshbuilder & required a full texture (similar to first image), xoppa (didn't cover 3D terrain)

Things I would like to take into account are low polygon count & no usage of a height-map.

Question's Summary:
Is there any tutorials/snippets to help better understand generating tiled/grid maps?
Is the method provided suitable for multi-texture painting similar to the second image?

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to create flat landscapes efficiently, or produce a height field on a flat map? In the former, what is it you don't like about your current implementation? In the latter, why the restriction to not using height maps? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve.